# Unity Slider mapped to list<float>?

Tags: list, unity-game-engine, slider

I currently have a `list<float>` that are arranged in an increasing order. My `sliders min.value` is the lowest value of my `list` (i.e. first element of my list) and `sliders max.value` is equal to the last item of my `list.`

What I want to do is that whenever my slider is at a specific `value` or `+-0.1` to one of the elements on my `list`, I Want to be able to get the `index` out that specific element to perform a task.

Any suggestions?

Someone asked for code, I don't even like this code since it only gives me the right value once I press "play" from zero, but then it removes my data, so I can't go back with the slider

this code is inside update void, and isPlaying is true when I press a "play" button

```
if(isPlaying){
    timeSlider.value += Time.deltaTime;
    timer = timeSlider.value;
    print(timeSlider.value);
    if((newTimes[0]>=(timer-0.1f)) && (newTimes[0]<=(timer+0.1f))){
          print("time: " + newTimes[0]+ " at run time: " + timer);
          NewTimes.RemoveAt(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok so where are stuck? Where is your code? Note that index is an int so you can't use float (0.1) there

Comment: I didn't see the benefit of including the non-existent code as I need suggestions to solve my question :P

Comment: I agree with you. There is no need to put effort into solving problem before posting it. If you just want a suggestion, the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46831430/3785314) in this question is a suggestion and that should fix your issue.

Comment: I have been trying to solve it for a very long time, this is my last resort, going to SO crying for help. I deemed that my code was not good enough and wouldn't even help me or you to solve my question so I decided not to include it.. I'm just an amateur programmer

But I did it now =/

Comment: "I deemed that my code was not good enough" there is no shame in learning, quite the opposite is true actually.

Comment: You can accept the answer @yes left if it solved your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the slider to use whole numbers in the inspector and use the value as your index?

[image]

Comment: This is what I would do (assuming that the float list doesn't have a fixed interval).

Comment: Thanks! will give it a look!

Comment: @VincentErikWong Don't forget to accept answer if it fixed your issue

Comment: Im new to stackoverflow and it is not the most intuitive website I have to say. I'm quite confused and I do not understand what or how to accept an answer.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought would be:

Set Slider Steps to Floats in your List
-> Perform task on List[currentSliderStep] as needed

Comment: Thanks, will check it!